# How many players are required for tournaments in Clash Royale?

Tags: clash-royale, competitive-gaming

I am new to Tournaments. I want to ask that how many players are required before tournament begins? Suppose in a 100 player tourney, if nobody joins, I guess gems will be refunded to creator. But what if only 3 people join? Will it start?

Also clear my doubt that If I am matched against Mr. X in tournament, how long before I can reconnect with him? Or I cannot unless I play with someone else first?

Comment: Please ask only one question per question.

Comment: Please consider opening the question after edit. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It *will* start anyway, even with a single player. The Gems would be refunded after the Tournament's end, if no battle was played during it.
*Also, you **need** to fight some other players before getting matched again with the same player.*